# I want to fill between two line: why it does not work

Tags: matlab

I want to fill between two line: why it does not work, if you make y axis in log scale it is more clear:

x1=[1e-15
1.00736565E-10
2.00736566E-10
3.00736575E-10
4.00736555E-10
5.00736563E-10
6.00736572E-10
7.0073658E-10
8.00736588E-10
9.00736541E-10
1.0007366E-09
1.10073661E-09
1.20073651E-09
1.30073652E-09
1.40073653E-09
1.50073654E-09
1.60073654E-09
1.70073655E-09
1.80073656E-09
1.90073646E-09
2.00073647E-09
2.10073647E-09
2.20073648E-09
2.30073649E-09
2.4007365E-09
2.50073651E-09
2.60073652E-09
2.70073652E-09
2.80073653E-09
2.90073654E-09
3.00073655E-09
3.10073656E-09
3.20073656E-09
3.30073657E-09
3.40073658E-09
3.50073659E-09
3.6007366E-09
3.70073661E-09
3.80073661E-09
3.90073662E-09
4.00073663E-09
4.10073664E-09
4.20073665E-09
4.30073666E-09
4.40073666E-09
4.50073667E-09
4.60073668E-09
4.70073669E-09
4.8007367E-09
4.90073671E-09
5.00073671E-09
5.10073672E-09
5.20073673E-09
5.30073674E-09
5.40073675E-09
5.50073675E-09
5.60073676E-09
5.70073677E-09
5.80073678E-09
5.90073634E-09
6.00073635E-09
6.10073636E-09
6.20073637E-09
6.30073638E-09
6.40073639E-09
6.50073639E-09
6.6007364E-09
6.70073641E-09
6.80073642E-09
6.90073643E-09
7.00000014E-09];
y1=[9.99999975E-05
0.000630573544
0.000570364238
0.000539087865
0.000522268645
0.000509617734
0.000505503966
0.000503603427
0.000501880422
0.000500597409
0.000494542764
0.000481754978
0.000472590938
0.000465609628
0.000461618358
0.000460371608
0.000457277027
0.000457367772
0.000455729692
0.000456139038
0.000455302361
0.000455120608
0.000455226866
0.000453888235
0.000452438398
0.000452370092
0.000452273292
0.000452234846
0.000452427892
0.000452812092
0.000453415996
0.000453897665
0.000453932822
0.000454381836
0.000454832538
0.000454123714
0.000452869019
0.000451409549
0.000449891377
0.000448385166
0.000446940219
0.00044556192
0.000444269972
0.000443059369
0.000441921904
0.000440850446
0.000439838041
0.000438877061
0.000437962357
0.000437091483
0.000436263683
0.000435475056
0.000434720569
0.000433999492
0.00043330976
0.000432648201
0.000432012603
0.00043139953
0.000430802873
0.000430215965
0.000429650187
0.0004291035
0.000428572646
0.000428059109
0.000427555904
0.000427069026
0.000426592625
0.000426132785
0.000425687584
0.000425255013
0.000424837577];
x2=[1e-15
1.00736565E-10
2.00736566E-10
3.00736575E-10
4.00736555E-10
5.00736563E-10
6.00736572E-10
7.0073658E-10
8.00736588E-10
9.00736541E-10
1.0007366E-09
1.10073661E-09
1.20073651E-09
1.30073652E-09
1.40073653E-09
1.50073654E-09
1.60073654E-09
1.70073655E-09
1.80073656E-09
1.90073646E-09
2.00073647E-09
2.10073647E-09
2.20073648E-09
2.30073649E-09
2.4007365E-09
2.50073651E-09
2.60073652E-09
2.70073652E-09
2.80073653E-09
2.90073654E-09
3.00073655E-09
3.10073656E-09
3.20073656E-09
3.30073657E-09
3.40073658E-09
3.50073659E-09
3.6007366E-09
3.70073661E-09
3.80073661E-09
3.90073662E-09
4.00073663E-09
4.10073664E-09
4.20073665E-09
4.30073666E-09
4.40073666E-09
4.50073667E-09
4.60073668E-09
4.70073669E-09
4.8007367E-09
4.90073671E-09
5.00073671E-09
5.10073672E-09
5.20073673E-09
5.30073674E-09
5.40073675E-09
5.50073675E-09
5.60073676E-09
5.70073677E-09
5.80073678E-09
5.90073634E-09
6.00073635E-09
6.10073636E-09
6.20073637E-09
6.30073638E-09
6.40073639E-09
6.50073639E-09
6.6007364E-09
6.70073641E-09
6.80073642E-09
6.90073643E-09
7.00000014E-09];
y2=[9.99999975E-05
0.0267447811
0.0306141321
0.0165520441
0.0153178349
0.0143728117
0.0136805847
0.0131568788
0.0127802808
0.0124623217
0.0122022089
0.0119882999
0.0118080974
0.0116490666
0.0115022063
0.0113633322
0.0112318601
0.0111074783
0.0109891901
0.010875551
0.0107701393
0.0106712151
0.0105776377
0.0104886796
0.0104038967
0.0103230448
0.0102459323
0.0101727787
0.0101033784
0.010037465
0.0099555254
0.00985758379
0.0097656725
0.00967914984
0.00959745795
0.0095201293
0.00944761187
0.00937952101
0.00931406766
0.00925118383
0.00919075124
0.00913263112
0.00907667447
0.00902273785
0.00897067972
0.0089203706
0.00886545517
0.00881648064
0.00876908656
0.00872316863
0.00867863093
0.00863538776
0.00859336182
0.00855247956
0.00851267762
0.0084738927
0.00843606982
0.00839915685
0.00836260337
0.00832583103
0.00829009339
0.00825531501
0.0082214307
0.00818838179
0.00815611705
0.00812459178
0.00809376314
0.00806359574
0.00803405512
0.00800511055
0.00797695667];
fill([x1.*1e9 fliplr(x2.*1e9)], [y1.*1e3,fliplr(y2.*1e3)],'r')

Comment: Haven't you heard of [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)???

Comment: Also, ever heard of [_minimal_ reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just confusing rows and columns: since `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` are columns, you need to concatenate vertically (with `;`) and flip vertically (with `flipud`):

```
fill([x1.*1e9; flipud(x2.*1e9)], [y1.*1e3; flipud(y2.*1e3)], 'r')
```

[image]